# Jagged screen edges

Tags: display

I see constant jagged lines on my screen. They start appearing after using Ubuntu for an hour or so. This has been a constant issue ever since last few Ubuntu releases.

I am using Intel DG31PR motherboard with Onboard graphics on a Core 2 Duo system. An currently using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit edition. Error has been occuring since v12.04 as far as I remember.

They start appearing randomly on icons and keep coming and going away.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

What to do?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a hardware problem, such as a loose plug?

Comment: Yes. I am sure because it happens only on Ubuntu. Everything is fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [Intel Graphic Drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) solved the issue for me.

Even though the 14.04 package is not available, 13.10 package somehow seemed to work fine in my case. Haven't noticed any formation of lines for the past 20 minutes now.

I guess the problem is gone for good now.